# randomforest model prediction error on new data

Tags: r

I am trying to train a randomForest model to take in new data but do not know why it is not working.

I read the data in from the clipboard using the following and build my RF model.

```
data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", strip.white = TRUE, sep = ',', header = FALSE, skip = 0)

y <- data[, 1]
x <- data[, 2]

rfmodel <- randomForest(y ~ x)
nd <- c(0.09, 0.9, 0.8)
predict(rfmodel, newdata = nd)
```

It throws an error out when the new data `nd` does not match the size of the training data.

Any help would be great since I do no know why the new data is not being "predicted".

Data:

```
2.81,5.62
7.14,8.00
2.72,5.44
3.87,7.74
1.90,3.80
7.82,8.00
7.02,8.00
5.50,8.00
9.15,8.00
4.87,8.00
8.08,8.00
5.58,8.00
9.13,8.00
0.14,0.28
2.00,4.00
5.47,8.00
0.80,1.60
4.37,8.00
5.31,8.00
0.00,0.00
1.78,3.56
3.45,6.90
6.13,8.00
3.53,7.06
4.61,8.00
1.76,3.52
6.39,8.00
0.02,0.04
9.69,8.00
5.33,8.00
6.37,8.00
5.55,8.00
7.80,8.00
2.06,4.12
7.79,8.00
2.24,4.48
9.71,8.00
1.11,2.22
8.38,8.00
2.33,4.66
1.83,3.66
5.94,8.00
9.20,8.00
1.14,2.28
4.15,8.00
8.43,8.00
5.68,8.00
8.21,8.00
1.75,3.50
2.16,4.32
4.93,8.00
5.75,8.00
1.26,2.52
3.97,7.94
4.39,8.00
7.53,8.00
1.98,3.96
1.66,3.32
2.04,4.08
11.72,8.00
4.64,8.00
4.71,8.00
3.77,7.54
9.33,8.00
1.83,3.66
2.15,4.30
1.58,3.16
9.29,8.00
1.27,2.54
8.49,8.00
5.39,8.00
3.47,6.94
6.48,8.00
4.11,8.00
1.85,3.70
8.79,8.00
0.13,0.26
1.44,2.88
5.96,8.00
3.42,6.84
1.89,3.78
1.98,3.96
5.26,8.00
0.39,0.78
6.05,8.00
1.99,3.98
1.58,3.16
3.99,7.98
4.35,8.00
6.71,8.00
2.58,5.16
7.37,8.00
5.77,8.00
3.97,7.94
3.65,7.30
4.38,8.00
8.06,8.00
8.05,8.00
1.10,2.20
6.65,8.00
```

Comment: can you provide sample data for x and y to make your question reproducible?

Comment: turn nd into a data.frame like this: `nd <- data.frame(x = c(0.09, 0.9, 0.8))`. At the moment you are trying to predict using a vector of numbers instead of line by line values.

Comment: That worked! But what I feed the randomForest model is a vector of numbers to train on, why can't I feed it a vector to test on also?

Comment: In the randomForest code the formula (y ~ x) is turned into a data.frame if y or x are not data.frames already. Hence new data needs to be a data.frame. This goes for all (or most) models that use predict. Just test it on `lm`. you will encounter the same issue.